# Software storage gateway

Tags: azure, local-storage, azure-cloud-services

I have a fileserver that containes about 2 TB of data and is growing with 50 000 files/40 gb each week.

Most of the files are just used a week or at most a month then they are not accessed.

The fileserver serves a couple of webservers with a shares for the files. And a webpage handles the upload and deleting of files throug the shares.

We dont want to keep expanding our on premis fileserver any more. And are looking for a cloud based hybrid storage.

We really dont want to rebuild any c# application or buy hardware like store simple.

What we are looking for is a solution wich copies all new files on a local drive to the cloud. Deletes locally files that has not been accessed for a month. If a user then wants a file that is deleted locally it first downloads from the cloud  and then we can use it. This should happend automatically.

I prefer to use blob storage in Azure as we already have some services there.

Any tip on how to do this?

Comment: This question is really broad, opinion-based (lots of ways to solve this), and could be considered a request for a tool recommendation (it's unclear from your question). All three of those reasons put this question as off-topic for StackOverflow. Whether you build, or buy is up to you.

Comment: I added that I want to use azure blob storage to narrow it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure blob storage would do the trick.  Blob storage works well for text, binaries, documents, media files etc. [This tutorial on blobs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/) should give you everything you need from the Azure side.  On the current file server you would just need to create a service or job that uploads all of the new files using the code from the tutorial.  Here's a quick approach that you can optimize, additionally you would need to write the logic to get the new files (I'm assuming that isn't a problem for you):

```
        // retreive all the new files
        List<System.IO.File> files = GetAllNewFiles(); 

        // Retrieve storage account from connection string.
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

        // Create the blob client.
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        // Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");

        // Retrieve reference to a blob named "myblob".
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("myblob");

        foreach (System.IO.File file in files)
        {
            // Create or overwrite the "myblob" blob with contents from a local file.
            using (var fileStream = file.OpenRead(@"path\myfile"))
            {
                blockBlob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
            }
        }
```

Additionally, if you didn't want to keep the files around forever on the cloud you could use a [Azure Scheduler](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/scheduler/) to run daily/weekly/monthly/whatever and delete all files that haven't been requested from your local file server in X days.

Comment: Do you mean that I should use the azure scheduler to connect to an on premise api to upload and delete files? I am really not familliar with all the services in Azure. I plan on writing the upload threaded. I asume that there shouldnt be a problem to run like 30 simultanious threads? Does the azure scheduler keep track if it already runs and don't start it if that is the case?

Comment: I was suggesting that you use the scheduler to monitor the Azure storage and delete files after a certain length of time.  I wouldn't get too caught up on where you do it, running both the upload/delete either locally or in the cloud would work, just depends on your specific situation.  I don't think threading is an issue with storage although I haven't personally tried it.

Comment: CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("myblob");
 that line should be inside the the foreach and the name should be the filename